# Getting a single value from fixer.io and use it on my website to multiply?

Tags: api, currency

I have a bunch of prices listed on my website, in British Punds. I would like to pull the current currency exchange rate into my website, to convert this value to another currency. It seems that fixer.io gets the data I need, but how do I pull it into my page? I only need 1 value form it.
My page loads the prices from a database, so I guess I need to multiply the database numbers with jQuery when the page is loaded.
Thats not my current issue though. I just want to figure out how to pull a single number, and be able to use it on my page.

Answer (score 0):

Good day. 
If you need to get currency rates for British Punds with fixer.io, you can make get request to

```
GET https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=GBP
```

And you will get latest foreign exchange reference rates for GBP.
If you don't need all list of currencies you may use something like

```
GET https://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=USD,EUR?base=GBP
```

And you will get exchange rates for USD and EUR with base GBP. 
Hope it will help you!